# Create PrivateKey and PublicKey having a byte array encoded in base 64

Tags: java, encryption, public-key, private-key

I have the `byte[]` with my private key (llave) and a `byte[]` with my public key (certificado=.

I need to convert these two values in a `PrivateKey` and `PublicKey` object (respectively) to use them later for signing digitally an xml document.

I have tried with `KeyStore` and I couldn't do it. I also tried with `KeyFactory` with the following code:

```
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.Collections;

import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.CanonicalizationMethod;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.DigestMethod;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.Reference;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.SignatureMethod;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.SignedInfo;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.Transform;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignature;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureFactory;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.dom.DOMSignContext;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo.KeyInfo;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo.KeyInfoFactory;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo.KeyValue;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.spec.C14NMethodParameterSpec;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.spec.TransformParameterSpec;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.DOMImplementation;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
public class GeneraXMLCancelacion {
public static void main (String [] args) {
    byte[] certificado = args[0].getBytes();
    byte[] llave = args[1].getBytes();
    String uuids = args[2];
    String rfc = args[3];
    String fecha = args[4];

    String [] uuid = uuids.split("/");

    //GENERAR XML
    try {
        //Crear un document XML vacío
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbfac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbfac.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder;
        docBuilder = dbfac.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
        doc.setXmlVersion("1.0");
        doc.setXmlStandalone(true);

        Element cancelacion = doc.createElementNS("http://cancelacfd.sat.gob.mx","Cancelacion");
        cancelacion.setAttribute("RfcEmisor", rfc);
        cancelacion.setAttribute("Fecha", fecha);
        doc.appendChild(cancelacion);

        Element folios = doc.createElementNS("http://cancelacfd.sat.gob.mx", "Folios");
        cancelacion.appendChild(folios);
        for (int i=0; i<uuid.length; i++) {
            Element u = doc.createElementNS("http://cancelacfd.sat.gob.mx","UUID");
            u.setTextContent(uuid[i]);
            folios.appendChild(u);
        }

        //create a keyfactory - use whichever algorithm and provider
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("DSA");
        //for private keys use PKCS8EncodedKeySpec; for public keys use X509EncodedKeySpec
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec ks = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(llave);
        PrivateKey privateKey = kf.generatePrivate(ks);
        X509EncodedKeySpec x = new X509EncodedKeySpec(certificado);
        PublicKey publicKey = kf.generatePublic(x);


        DOMSignContext dsc = new DOMSignContext (privateKey, doc.getDocumentElement()); 
        XMLSignatureFactory fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");

        Reference ref = fac.newReference ("", fac.newDigestMethod(DigestMethod.SHA1, null), 
                    Collections.singletonList
                    (fac.newTransform(Transform.ENVELOPED,
                    (TransformParameterSpec) null)), null, null);
        KeyInfoFactory kif = fac.getKeyInfoFactory();
        KeyValue kv = kif.newKeyValue(publicKey);
        KeyInfo ki = kif.newKeyInfo(Collections.singletonList(kv)); 

        SignedInfo si = fac.newSignedInfo
                  (fac.newCanonicalizationMethod
                    (CanonicalizationMethod.INCLUSIVE_WITH_COMMENTS,
                      (C14NMethodParameterSpec) null),
                    fac.newSignatureMethod(SignatureMethod.DSA_SHA1, null),
                    Collections.singletonList(ref)); 

        KeyInfoFactory kif2 = fac.getKeyInfoFactory();
        KeyValue kv2 = kif2.newKeyValue(publicKey);
        KeyInfo ki2 = kif.newKeyInfo(Collections.singletonList(kv)); 

        XMLSignature signature = fac.newXMLSignature(si, ki);

        signature.sign(dsc);

        //IMPRIMIR EL DOCUMENTO XML
        TransformerFactory transfac = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer trans = transfac.newTransformer();
        trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
        trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.VERSION, "1.0");
        trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

        //CREAR STRING DEL ARBOL XML
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        trans.transform(source, result);
        String xmlString = sw.toString();
        System.out.println(xmlString);
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

When running the program I get this error:

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Inappropriate key specification: invalid key format
at sun.security.provider.DSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePrivate(Unknown Source)
at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePrivate(Unknown Source)
at vital.cancelaciones.GeneraXMLCancelacion.main(GeneraXMLCancelacion.java:85)
```

Line 85 corresponds to:

> PrivateKey privateKey = kf.generatePrivate(ks);

If anyone has any better solution, I would appreciate your help.

Comment: What code is in the line 85 of your `GeneraXMLCancelacion.java` file? Can you add the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to your post?

Comment: I already edited the code to include it all

Comment: You should add all imports to your code. Without them it's hard to guess which classes you are using.

Comment: Try to comment the line 85. Does compilation succed after that?

Comment: Try to use `X509EncodedKeySpec` instead of `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec`.

Comment: I get the same error. If I comment the privateKey the error appears as well in PublicKey, and the program can't go on because it needs these two objects to perfom the digital signature

Comment: Ok. Now I'm able to compile your code. Which parameter you are running it with?

Comment: And what about `DSAPrivateKeySpec`? See [this list of specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/security/spec/KeySpec.html).

Comment: args[0] --> certificate (public key) in base 64 / args[1] --> private key in base 64 / args[2] --> BD6CA3B1-E565-4985-88A9-694A6DD48448 / args[3] --> doesnt matter / args[4] --> Date (yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss)

Comment: I just realized that my private and public keys are encoded using ASN1 DER. Any ideas of how can I convert it into PrivateKey and PublicKey in Java?

Comment: Check the [how-do-i-decode-a-der-encoded-string-in-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409618/how-do-i-decode-a-der-encoded-string-in-java) thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a similar code that I know works and it is similar to yours:

```
 public KeyPair createKeyPair(byte[] encodedPrivateKey, byte[] encodedPublicKey) {
    try {
        EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encodedPrivateKey);
        KeyFactory generator = KeyFactory.getInstance(ASYM_ALGORITHM);
        PrivateKey privateKey = generator.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);

        EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(encodedPublicKey);
        PublicKey publicKey = generator.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);
        return new KeyPair(publicKey, privateKey);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Failed to create KeyPair from provided encoded keys", e);
    }
}
```

I think the byte array for the key is wrong. How do you pass it to the main method?

Comment: The byte array is stored in the database and I get this records from it, pass them to the main method and try to create the keys. I used this same Strings in Visual Basic and the encryptation algorithms work fine. I don't know why Java doesn't consider it as a valid byte array...

Comment: In that case maybe the string is encoded in a different character set. Try using the explicit character set to turn the byte array into string. For example `args[1].getBytes("UTF8");`