# How can I access the decoded text from my Android app?

Tags: java, javascript, android, algorithm, asn.1

I'm working on an Android app, that connects to a .crl file on the Internet and gets some data from it. I need to be able to decode this file (for example with ASN.1 JavaScript decoder - http://lapo.it/asn1js/#) and then use the decoded data.

My question is, how can I access the decoded data from my Android app? Is there some way to reference the decoded text online? Or is there a way, to include the decoder JavaScript in my Android app? I have very basic knowledge in JavaScript.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409618/how-do-i-decode-a-der-encoded-string-in-java

Comment: @Marc B, I have checked your link and if I am right, this is the code which decodes the text but how can I connect this code to the URL of my file?