# How can I convert X509 extension bytes to readable string?

Tags: java

I can get extension value in byte array.

```
byte[] value = x509Cert.getExtensionValue(oid);
```

How can I read the value?

Comment: [new String(value)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A-)?

Comment: What is the format you want to have your bytes in? Hexadecimal values?

Comment: @rmlan it caused messy code

Comment: @zhh don't put parts of your actual question in comments. What question are you actually asking, because the subject line and the body of the question do not match very closely. Explain how creating a new String is not what works for you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I think, this may help you, since hex-values or a base64 encoded string is actually not readable for humans:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13802277/5847341